# Codeigniter with UTF8 uris

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8

I am experiencing a weird issue with Codeigniter. I hope some of you encountered it before and can point me to the right direction.

I am working with utf8 urls such as:

> read/セイコー-逆輸入-55446ef2d0f02

This is translated correctly to:

> read/%E3%82%BB%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC-%E9%80%86%E8%BC%B8%E5%85%A5-55446ef2d0f02

The problem starts as soon as I use the internal URI functions of codeigniter:

Output of:

```
$slug = basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
var_dump($slug );
```

> string(78) "%E3%82%BB%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC-%E9%80%86%E8%BC%B8%E5%85%A5-55446ef2d0f02"

Output of:

```
$slug = $this->uri->segment(3);
var_dump($slug);
```

is:

> string(36) "ã‚»ã‚¤ã‚³ãƒ¼-é€†è¼¸å…¥-55446ef2d0f02"

Internal codeigniter encoding and page encoding are both set to UTF-8

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How did you prove the page/output encoding? What are the HTTP response headers?

Comment: try urldecode($this->uri->segment(3));

Comment: @saty tried already the urldecode method and I get same exact output